# What does the declaration "String^ strtests" in C++/CLI mean?

Tags: c++, .net, templates, declaration, managed-c++

I am just confused by the syntax below:

```
T1<T2^>^ templatetest;
Sting^ strtest;
[this]()->...
```

Comment: This is not 'clean' C++ but [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Comment: @Adam  This means nothing in C++. It can have meaning in C++/CLI but C++/CLI is not C++. and never was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` in C++/CLI is analog of `*` in C++. Objects decrared with `^` and allocated by `gcnew` will be stored in managed memory and freed automatically then number of pointers on that memory became 0.

Comment: Thanks , C++/CLI and C++/CX both support this ??

Comment: C++/CX has `^` and `ref new` operators, but mechanism of feeing memory is different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX